# How can I center a linear layout to the middle of its parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am in the process of writing my first full Android app, and I want to center a linear layout so that the layout **itself** is centered, not just the content inside of the layout. I have seen through old posts that `android:layout_gravity` is used to do this, but as I enter that into my activity's XML, [there are no suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miKv7.png), and [nothing happens when fully entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZEwf.png).

Am I not supposed to use a linear layout to achieve this? Am I supposed to make its size `match_parent` and just constrain the sizes of all of its children? My idea for the layout was to constrain the size of the linear layout, center it, and have all of its children's horizontal size `match_parent`.

Here is my activity's XML for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.frc5113.combustiblescouting.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Team Number" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When using `ConstraintLayout` switch to **Design** tab of layout editor in the android studio, it will be more helpful to achieve your design.

Comment: @android_hub I've heard that it is easier to use the design tab for ConstraintLayouts. What about it is easier? What other types of main layouts are there that are better with the text tab?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 As I said in the post, `android:layout_gravity` does not work. It does not do anything, and is not a suggestion when I begin to type it out. Also, I described what I want my layout to look like in the post: Fixed, smaller sized EditTexts. Setting it to `match_parent` makes it stretch across the entire screen, unless I set each EditText to a fixed size. Is that what I am supposed to do?

Comment: `LinearLayout` would be the most easier choice for your design, and if you don't want to set a fixed size for each `EditText` then you can go for `layout_marginRight` and `layout_marginLeft`

Comment: @android_hub Thank you! I was not aware that there was a surrounding ConstraintLayout. So is changing the margins is more of a common practice than making the layout a fixed size and centering is?

Comment: If you want a more elegant solution then make `LinearLayout` as a parent and create a common `style` for the child views in `style.xml`, common styles here would be `width` of the views and use it for child views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root layout is a `ConstraintLayout`. I don't think that supports the attribute `layout_gravity`. You should either use `LinearLayout` or use constraints relative to your root view as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is I think what I was looking for. I was not aware that there was a surrounding ConstraintLayout. Should I switch that to a LinearLayout, or is that bad practice?

Comment: I won't call that a bad practice since ConstraintLayout has been fairly recently introduced. It has its benefits. You can switch to LinearLayout but I would recommend learning ConstraintLayout as well, as its quite powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it makes your containt horizontal & vertical center simultaneously:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="com.frc5113.combustiblescouting.MainActivity"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:gravity="center">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Team Number" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

using `android:gravity="center"` on the LinearLayout will center it's **childs**  not itself.

There would be the `android:layout_gravity` attribute which is telling the parent how this child wants to be layed out. But this needs to be supported by the Containers' LayoutParams (which is true for e.g. FrameLayout, LinearLayout...)
But Constraintlayout does not support this kind of child gravity.
Here you need to set Constraints on the child (in your case the LinearLayout) in order to place it properly.

Therefore if you want to center the LinearLayout (which would somehow be obsolete as you could center it's childs directly in the ConstraintLayout)
you can achieve this like the following:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <!-- content -->

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```